# Extracting/Decompiling Multiple Python Files Using PyDecipher

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I have an **exe** written in Python and Compiled using PyInstaller.
However, I would like to reverse it into the original Python File(s).

I successfully managed to decompile the file on Linux using PyDecipher, but the problem is, I only see one file from the project, plus a bunch of other unrelated files, and the other project files are amiss.
The structure was like:

```
Project
  includes
    database.py
    convertor.py
  records
    names.csv
  app.py
  libraries.py
  config.py
```

As can be seen above, **app.py** imports *config.py* and *libraries.py* which also in turn imports files from **includes** directory.
Eventually, I created **.exe** using **PyInstaller**, but when I extract the *exe* using **PyDecipher**, only **app.py** was found. The rest are nowhere to be seen.

I've been scurrying the web, but I don't seem to find any satisfactory answer.

Any help will be handsomely appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: PyDecipher hasn’t been updated in over 2 years. It’s highly possible that the freezing techniques used today have evolved past those that were supported by PyDecipher at the time of its last release.

Comment: That makes a hint... am using Python 3.9 though. I wonder if this could also possibly have an impact?